# Python, Linux: How to delete unicode files?

Tags: python, linux, unicode, ubuntu

I have a file whose name contains accents.

I'm trying to use Python's os.remove to delete it, but I keep getting an UnicodeDecodeError.

I'm using Ubuntu, Python 2.6 and my locale LANG=en_US.utf-8

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? There's probably an error in it.

Comment: @Mark: "There's probably an error in it." -- made my day!

Comment: Yeah, post code; what you think is happening, is not. `os.remove` will not itself issue a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Answer (score 5):

There are no "unicode files" in Linux. Encode your `unicode` with the encoding used by the filesystem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you are doing this:

```
os.unlink(u"Thé file näme.dôc")
```

Try this instead:

```
os.unlink(u"Thé file näme.dôc".encode("utf8"))
```